# Smooth curve between two points?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have two CGPoints. I need to draw a curve from one to the other. How can I draw it? Core graphics or Bezier path? If so, I need some guidance please. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What you want to draw  is a Bezier Path.
but when you say a curve, there can be thousands of smooth curve going through two points.

A bezier Curve always has two control points apart from the end points.

Control Points determine how the curve will bend.
So i just want a smooth curve to go through two points take any random control points.
Or provide control points that determine how the curve should bend.
if there are a lot of points then what you are looking for is a bezier spline.

Comment: With just two points, one beginning and one end, can't I just draw the curve with a slight bend?

Comment: You need at least one additional point to specify **how much** that you want it to bend.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UIBezierPath` or CGPath . 
`UIBezierPath` works like `NSBezierPath` on OS X. 
In your view's drawRect: method,
Declare the object

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
```

Then start the first point.

```
[aPath moveToPoint: startPoint];
```

Next add a curved segment with control points. 
This is the hard part figuring out where control points need to be.

There are two kinds. 
Cubic curve

```
[aPath addCurveToPoint: aDestinationPoint controlPoint1: aControlPoint controlPoint2: anotherControlPoint];
```

Quadratic curve

```
[aPath addQuadCurveToPoint:aDestinationPoint  controlPoint: aLonelyControlPoint];
```

Finally, call the set method on a UIColor (NSColor on Mac). 
Then stroke or fill the path.

```
[aPath stroke];
```

You might also want to set the stroke width.

Remember drawing is back to front procedurally and if you want a different color call set on a different color before the next drawing command of fill or stroke

The CG version of events is similar but more convoluted.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html